# Jenkins : Unable to uninstall Flexible Publish Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I had installed the `Flexible Publish Plugin` through the `Jenkins` Web module by marking it for `Install without restart` option. The plugin installation went fine. The real trouble is when you want to uninstall the application.

Jenkins web module is not letting me uninstall or disable this plugin because of a dependency tree that has been created.

[image: Popup displayed when hovering on uninstall button]

`Flexible Publish Plugin
  |_ Artifactory Plugin`

AFAIK, the `Artifactory Plugin` was installed even before I installed `Flexible Publish Plugin` but still it is showing up as a dependency for `Flexible Publish Plugin`.

Is there any other workaround to uninstall the plugin?

NOTE : I couldn't find any `.hpi` or `.jpi` file corresponding to `Flexible Publish Plugin` so I am not able to disable the plugin manually from the folder as well.

Comment: The files in `jenkins/plugins` are named `*.jpi`, not `*.hpi`. And you don't have to delete them, you can rename them to `*.jpi.disabled`.

Comment: I am using jenkins `1.633` as a war file. I have plugins there under jenkins/WEB-INF/plugins with extension `.hpi`. I tried searching anything matching `*.jpi` but couldn't locate it.

Comment: I have `*.hpi`s in `jenkins/war/WEB-INF/plugins`, too, but there's no `flexible-publish.hpi`. It's `jenkins/plugins/flexible-publish.jpi` here.

Comment: I have directly deployed `jenkins.war` file on `tomcat`. There is no folder named `plugins` inside `jenkins`.

Comment: Is there a `~/.jenkins/plugins`?

Comment: Yes, found that folder. It's in there. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tomcat/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/plugins` contains just `*.hpi`.

`~/.jenkins/plugins` contains `*.jpi`.

See [Jenkins – The Definitive Guide, The Jenkins Home Directory](https://books.google.at/books?id=pQ-DG7aT0IgC&lpg=PA41&hl=de&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> By default, the Jenkins home directory will be called *.jenkins*, and will be placed in your home directory.